# Velocity templates not substituting methods

Tags: velocity

In the [Velocity User's Guide](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/devel/user-guide.html#methods) it seems pretty straight forward to use methods in templates.
I tried, but could not make it work. Can someone tell me what I did wrong?

Thanks.

This is my code

```
@Test
public void testVelocity() {
  Velocity.init();
  VelocityContext map = new VelocityContext();
  map.put("test", "Success");
  map.put("ok", "OK!");
  map.put("func", new Object() {public String test() {return "Yay!";}});
  map.put("func2", new Object() {public String test(String t) {return t+t;}});

  String template = "${func.test()} $test $func2.test($ok)";
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
  Velocity.evaluate(map, writer, "", new StringReader(template));
  assertEquals("Yay! Success OK!OK!", writer.toString());
}
```

and this is the output:

```
org.junit.ComparisonFailure: 
Expected :Yay! Success OK!OK!
Actual   :${func.test()} Success $func2.test($ok)
```

Variable substitutions seems to work fine, but not method calls.

Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that for security reasons Velocity only allows calling **public methods** of **public classes**. An anonymous class is not public, thus the call is blocked.

It would work if you put a real object, an instance of a public class.

It would also work if you disable the secure uberspector, but that is not a good idea, since it opens up the system.

Comment: Thanks! That helped! I was doing a POC so I didn't bother with creating 'real' classes...