# Sometimes velocity does not substitute

Tags: java, velocity, template-engine

Sometimes the following code generates `$position.getComment()` in a template. Same for other fields. But it is occasional behavior. What might be the reason and how to fix?

```
#if($position.hasComment())
    <td>$position.getComment()</td>
#else
    <td class="empty">&mdash;</td>
#end
```

Position's comment is String and `hasComment` is following

```
public boolean hasComment() {
    return comment != null;
}
```

Some log with might be useful at Velocity startup

```
velocity - Velocimacro : allowInline = true : VMs can be defined inline in templates
velocity - Velocimacro : allowInlineToOverride = false : VMs defined inline may NOT replace previous VM definitions
velocity - Velocimacro : allowInlineLocal = false : VMs defined inline will be global in scope if allowed.
```

[Velocity templates not substituting methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233883/velocity-templates-not-substituting-methods)

Comment: What value is `comment` when this behaviour occurs? Are you setting the context before rendering the template?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this:

```
#if (! $position.getComment() || "$position.getComment()" == "")
    <td class="empty">&mdash;</td>
#else
    <td>$position.getComment()</td>
#end
```

I'm new on velocity, so I can't completely explain you why, but I've been programming for two weeks some HTML templates for a new project and on my team we've found this way is the best way to do it.